# Correct struct definition

Tags: elixir

How to define the struct in the correct way, look at the following code snippet:

```
defmodule SapOdataService.Worker do
  defstruct uri: "", user: nil, password: nil
```

Should I define the default value as nil or?

Comment: Depends on your usecase, you can define custom default values or just pass a list of atoms to the `defstruct` and every value will have a nil as a default, which may make sense in your case I guess.

Comment: What is mean depends on my case?

Comment: Well, sometimes, for let's say `url` value it makes sense to leave nil as a default value, sometimes it makes sense to make "https://example.com" as a default value, sometimes it makes sense to make it an empty string and etc. It's completely up to you and what you think it more suitable for your situation.

Comment: You can also combine both and write something like `defstruct [:user, :password, url: ""]`, so you don't have to repeat `nil` over and over.

Comment: Thanks so much guys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a few options.

1. You can list the key value pairs explicitly using `nil` for blank values

   ```
   defmodule User do
     defstruct name: "zero_coding", age: nil
   end
   ```
2. You can pass a list of atoms that will all default to nil:

   ```
   defmodule User do
     defstruct [:name, :age]
   end
   ```
3. You can do a mix of the above a list of atoms that will all default to nil:

   ```
   defmodule User do
     defstruct [:age, name: "zero_coding"] 
   end
   ```
4. You can also enforce specific keys that must be specified when creating the struct

   ```
   defmodule User do
     @enforce_keys [:name]
     defstruct [:name, :age]
   end
   ```

Comment: here type 3 only works if you put first all the default-less (implicit `nil`) first, then the explicit defaults.  `defstruct [name: "zero_coding", :age]` gives error.